# jQuery SVG failed to add image

Tags: jquery, svg

I'm trying to add image under g tag with id "stationMarks" using jQuery SVG, but it seems like "var svg = $('#stationMarks').svg('get');" doesn't work, code as below:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>    
    <!--<script src="jquery/d3/d3.min.js">
    </script>-->
    <script src="jquery/jquery.svg.package-1.4.5/jquery.svg.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery/jquery.svg.package-1.4.5/jquery.svganim.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery/jquery.svg.package-1.4.5/jquery.svgdom.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery/jquery.svg.package-1.4.5/jquery.svgfilter.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery/jquery.svg.package-1.4.5/jquery.svgplot.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery/jquery.svg.package-1.4.5/jquery.svggraph.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery/jquery-1.7.2.js"></script><!-- moved to the top according to advice, but the image still not added-->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            var svg = $('#stationMarks').svg('get');

            var cx = 21.0526903136934 * 120.343434 - 1470.84140760084;
            var cy = -21.9878694270822 * 43.343434 + 1859.94190338842;

            var cx_locate = cx - 10.5;
            var imageRef = 'swf/siteok.png';

            var image = svg.image(cx - 10.5, cy - 25, 21, 25, 'swf/siteok.png', { id: 'img' });
        });

    </script>
</head>
<body>
<svg width="1584pt" height="2448pt" viewBox="0 0 1584 2448" enable-background="new 0 0 1584 2448"
version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" >
    <g>
...
        <g id="stationMarks">
        </g>
    </g>
</svg>
</body>
</html>
```

Could anyone give some idea what's wrong with it?
Thanks!

It seems like "svg.image(cx - 10.5, cy - 25, 21, 25, 'swf/siteok.png', { id: 'img' });" is not working as well, but I find no error according to the reference...Any suggestion?

Comment: Finally, I turned to use 'getAttributeNS' and 'setAttributeNS' instead, quite a pity I failed to manipulate doms with jquery.svg, it would make my work easier, so far it works. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jquery library be first of the head tag. Reorder the jquery library always on top of other scripts

```
 <script src="jquery/jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>
     <script src="jquery/jquery.svg.package-1.4.5/jquery.svg.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery/jquery.svg.package-1.4.5/jquery.svganim.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery/jquery.svg.package-1.4.5/jquery.svgdom.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery/jquery.svg.package-1.4.5/jquery.svgfilter.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery/jquery.svg.package-1.4.5/jquery.svgplot.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery/jquery.svg.package-1.4.5/jquery.svggraph.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it makes "var svg = $('#stationMarks').svg('get');" works and is one of the keys. But the image is still not added...

Answer (score 0):

The issue is you are adding jquery file at the last. add the jquery file first and then the others.

The reason for this is the others are built on jquery, when they are included their properties and functionality lookout for jquery file which was not included by then.

so the order could be like this:

```
<script src="jquery/jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>
<script src="jquery/jquery.svg.package-1.4.5/jquery.svg.js"></script>
<script src="jquery/jquery.svg.package-1.4.5/jquery.svganim.js"></script>
<script src="jquery/jquery.svg.package-1.4.5/jquery.svgdom.js"></script>
<script src="jquery/jquery.svg.package-1.4.5/jquery.svgfilter.js"></script>
<script src="jquery/jquery.svg.package-1.4.5/jquery.svgplot.js"></script>
<script src="jquery/jquery.svg.package-1.4.5/jquery.svggraph.js"></script>
```

This will work.